# Como usar o "for" e "While" para capturar tags de céluas de vária tabelas em um arquivo html?

Tags: python-3.x, while, for

Tenho vários arquivos de HTML que preciso capturar os dados dentro das tabelas, para lançar no banco, mas não estou conseguindo navegar na árvore de html para encontrar as tags que são células, o html é esse:

```
<div class="details">
   <div class="title-table"><h2> BEAUNE</h2>
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <div class="table-towers">
        <div id="table472dc5e9b46304cf95865f7db6c459aa" class="collapse in table-content">
           <div class="table-towers">
                 <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-cell build_type">Apartamento</div>
                    <div class="table-cell area_useful">220m²</div>
                    <div class="table-cell rooms">3</div>
                    <div class="table-cell garage">4</div>
                    <div class="table-cell bird_estimate_average">R$ 2.816.344,33*
            <p><small>(R$ 2.393.892,68 a R$ 3.238.795,98)</small></p>
        </div>
                 <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell build_type">Cobertura</div>
                    <div class="table-cell area_useful">396m²</div>
                    <div class="table-cell rooms">3</div>
                    <div class="table-cell garage">5</div>
                    <div class="table-cell bird_estimate_average">R$ 5.069.419,80*
                             <p><small>(R$ 4.309.006,83 a R$ 5.829.832,77)</small></p>
                     </div>
   <div class="title-table"><h2>BERGERAC</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive">
          <div class="table-towers">
               <div id="table0b60c9a0a450b921186c91102da447d9" class="collapse table-content">
                   <div class="table-towers">
                       <div class="table-row">
                            <div class="table-cell build_type">Apartamento</div>
                    <div class="table-cell area_useful">220m²</div>
                    <div class="table-cell rooms">3</div>
                    <div class="table-cell garage">4</div>
                    <div class="table-cell bird_estimate_average">R$ 2.816.344,33*
                               <p><small>(R$ 2.393.892,68 a R$ 3.238.795,98)</small></p>
                 </div>
                                            <!-- asdasd -->
                </div>
                        </div>
```

Aí tenho mais 10 tabelas, dentro de um arquivo de HTML, que segue a mesma estrutura, então pensei em fazer um "for" pra ele trazer a tag "title-table" que é o nome da tabela assim:

```
for id_torre in soup.find("div",{"class":"details"}).findAll("div",{"class":"title-table"}):#.findAll("h2"):
nm = id_torre.find("h2")
print(nm)
```

E com a lista dos títulos das tabelas, pensei em por no "while" pra que ele encontre a tabela com cada título e depois captura-se os dados das células em cada linha, pra depois eu lançar no banco de dados:

```
while len(id_torre) >0:
nm = id_torre
print(nm)

tipo = soup.find("div",{"class":id_torre}).find("div",{"class":"table-cell build_type"})
print(tipo)

m2_util = soup.find("div",{"class":id_torre}).find("div",{"class":"table-cell area_useful"})
print(m2_util)

dt = soup.find("div",{"class":id_torre}).find("div",{"class":"table-cell rooms"})
print(dt)
```

Porém ele traz "none" em todos campos e fica dando loop infinitamente. o que está de errado no código? sou novo em programação e o python é a  primeira linguagem que estou aprendendo.

Comment: Todas as tabelas têm o titulo em um <h2> dentro de da class table-title? Neste caso é BEAUNE, certo?

Comment: sim, todas tem título dentro de <h2>, neste caso são duas tabelas, uma com nome BEAUNE  e outra com BERGERAC, porém cada tabela tem uma (<div id="table......) também

Comment: E quer o texto dentro dos elementos cuja classe é table-cell e a que tabela pertencem correto?

Comment: correto, preciso da class=table-cell de cada tabela relacionado ao nome da tabela, pra lançar no banco

Comment: Eu tenho o arquivo HTML completo, aqui só coloquei uma parte quer q te envie?

Comment: Não preciso, faço consoante o que colocou aqui, sem problema

Comment: '\nBERGERAC': ['\nApartamento\n', '\n220m��\n', '\n3', '\n4', '\nR$ 2.816.344,33*\n\n\n(R$ 2.393.892,68 a R$ 3.238.795,98)\n\n\n','\nCobertura\n', '\n396m��\n', '\n3', '\n5', '\nR$ 5.069.419,80*\n\n\n(R$ 4.309.006,83 a R$ 5.829.832,77)\n\n\n'],

Comment: Ele trouxe assim, mas como tiro os "\n" e elimino os espaços dos textos?

Comment: Estou ainda a ver uma solução, veja se essa em baixo ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Abra o arquivo usando a função open (exemplo: arquivo = open('nomedoarquivo.tipo'), assim você pode usar esse arquivo em um for(onde não existiria loop infinito), onde ele vai passar de linha em linha, a biblioteca re pode ser mais útil do que o find se você souber expressão regular, com a biblioteca re, da pra achar por exemplo nessa linha `

> '<'div class="table-cell build_type"'>'Apartamento'<'/div'>'

` os

> '<'...'>'Apartamento'<'/...'>'

os ' ', são por que o conteúdo estava ficando oculto

e extrair a palavra 'Apartamento' e assim salvar ela num banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Este html possui diversas tags não fechadas e é por isso que o parser do BeautifulSoup está perdido. Você pode verificar as falhas neste site: https://www.aliciaramirez.com/closing-tags-checker/

The following tags don't seem to be closed:

```
Line 1: <div class="details">
Line 2: <div class="title-table">
Line 3: <div class="table-responsive">
Line 4: <div class="table-towers">
Line 5: <div id="table472dc5e9b46304cf95865f7db6c459aa" class="collapse in table-content">
Line 6: <div class="table-towers">
Line 7: <div class="table-row">
Line 15: <div class="table-row">
Line 23: <div class="title-table">
Line 24: <div class="table-responsive">
Line 25: <div class="table-towers">
Line 26: <div id="table0b60c9a0a450b921186c91102da447d9" class="collapse table-content">
```

Caso não tenha colado o código completo peço que o faça. Se a página realmente contiver estes erros cole o código completo nos avise para que possamos ajudar.